# use of apply function to shift values of a column to another column of corresponding columns

Tags: python, pandas, data-science

I have encountered some problems with my data that value of one column shifted to another column for the corresponding row. I need to shift back those values to its original column based on some conditions.

I am providing a sample dataframe which describes my dataset except that my original data has 50 columns in it, but the sample dataframe has only 3 columns.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = {'A': [100,200,np.nan,400,np.nan ,600,np.nan , np.nan], 'B': [8, 9,np.nan , 11, 500, 13, 700, 15 ], 
        'C': [np.nan,np.nan,300, np.nan, 12,np.nan , 14, np.nan]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data, index = pd.date_range("2021-02-01", periods=8, freq="24H"))
print(df)


Out:
               A    B   C
2021-02-01  100.0   8.0  NaN
2021-02-02  200.0   9.0  NaN
2021-02-03  NaN  NaN  300.0
2021-02-04  400.0 11.0 NaN
2021-02-05  NaN 500.0   12.0
2021-02-06  600.0   13.0 NaN
2021-02-07  NaN 700.0   14.0
2021-02-08  NaN 15.0    NaN
```

I need to shift those values in column `['B' , 'C']` which are greater than the correspond columns to its original column that is `['A']`

Looking forward for some solution from the experts over here.
Thank you in advance.
regards, Sambit

Comment: Can you also provide a sample expected output?

Answer (score 0):

- assigned back to new column **A2** for purpose of transparency
- used numpy `select()` with two conditions,  checking B & C.  Assume **NaN** in **A** is zero
- given conditions,  then take value from appropriate column
- default column unchanged

```
data = {'A': [100,200,np.nan,400,np.nan ,600,np.nan , np.nan], 'B': [8, 9,np.nan , 11, 500, 13, 700, 15 ], 
        'C': [np.nan,np.nan,300, np.nan, 12,np.nan , 14, np.nan]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data, index = pd.date_range("2021-02-01", periods=8, freq="24H"))
df = df.assign(A2=np.select([df.B.gt(df.A.fillna(0)),df.C.gt(df.A.fillna(0))], [df.B,df.C], df.A))
```

|  | A | B | C | A2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-02-01 00:00:00 | 100 | 8 | nan | 100 |
| 2021-02-02 00:00:00 | 200 | 9 | nan | 200 |
| 2021-02-03 00:00:00 | nan | nan | 300 | 300 |
| 2021-02-04 00:00:00 | 400 | 11 | nan | 400 |
| 2021-02-05 00:00:00 | nan | 500 | 12 | 500 |
| 2021-02-06 00:00:00 | 600 | 13 | nan | 600 |
| 2021-02-07 00:00:00 | nan | 700 | 14 | 700 |
| 2021-02-08 00:00:00 | nan | 15 | nan | 15 |

Comment: Thank you very much for your quick reply. It was a nice explanation but can you suggest some pandas methods?

Comment: pandas and numpy are bed fellows... pandas is built on top of numpy.  IMHO using numpy capabilities with pandas is pandas :-)